# PHP preg_match_all functions regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Below is an example segment of text that I'm using to search for any hashtags in my wordpress site, creating them into a link. I'm using the regex PHP preg_match_all function to do so.

> A useful accessory to these traps is the **#2823** CO² gas regulator kit
>   designed for use in areas where dry ice cannot be obtained or is not
>   desired.  Adding the CO² gas regulator kit increases the catch rate
>   for many mosquito species as well as black flies, stable flies, biting
>   midges and New World sand flies. For more control as to how long the
>   regulator runs, using the **#2880CT** timer is recommended for unattended
>   stop and start collecting times.
>
> A rain shield is now available for the BG-2 Sentinel trap.
>
> For other replacement items see: Green Carrying Bag **#2880GCC**, CO²
>   Emitter Nozzle **#2880CO**, No-See-Um Mesh Catch Bag **#2880CNS1**.

Using the line of PHP below, it finds all the numbers and just the first letter included in the hashtags provided in the segment, it ignores and leaves out any remaining characters in the hashtag.

(e.g. #2880GCC only grabs #2880G)

```
preg_match_all( apply_filters( "wpht_regex_pattern", '/#(\w{4,10})/u'), strip_tags($content), $hashtags );
```

Using the line of PHP below, it finds all the numbers and letters but ignores any hashtag that does not have any letters following the numbers.

(e.g. #2823)

```
preg_match_all( apply_filters( "wpht_regex_pattern", '/#(\w\w{4,10})/u'), strip_tags($content), $hashtags );
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: What does `wpht_regex_pattern` do? How does it adapt the pattern? (Because, you know, the first regex by itself would do the job already.)

Comment: @user3783243 the expected behavior is to grab the full content following a hashtag, ignoring any non alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @mario I believe that its a hook that the original developer used. I'm exactly sure, but when I try to remove it, it stops any function from happening

Comment: Functions as expected here, https://3v4l.org/GmdVG, The `wpht_regex_pattern` must be doing something. (The `\w` includes an `_` as well but that is not related to your current issue, that would just overmatch)

Comment: It either sets the Ungreedy flag, or reverses the polarity of the main deflector. Both of which you do not want in this case.

Comment: @user3783243 Here is the full line of php https://3v4l.org/en17I

Comment: @bworkman What does `wpht_regex_pattern` do? That is your issue. Can you update to show how you removed that and it stopped working? Maybe it created a syntax error?

Comment: @user3783243 I removed it as `preg_match_all( apply_filters( '/#(\w{4,10})/u'), strip_tags($content), $hashtags );`

Comment: Dont use `apply_filters`.

Answer (score 0):

With your exising [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/26) and an extra non-capturing group `?:`. It should match all the words with a `#` preceding the alpha-numeric value.

```
 #(?:\w{4,10})
```

**OR**

```
 #(?:[A-Z0-9]+)


<?php
$re = '/#(?:[A-Z0-9]+)/u';
$str = 'A useful accessory to these traps is the #2823 CO² gas regulator kit designed for use in areas where dry ice cannot be obtained or is not desired. Adding the CO² gas regulator kit increases the catch rate for many mosquito species as well as black flies, stable flies, biting midges and New World sand flies. For more control as to how long the regulator runs, using the #2880CT timer is recommended for unattended stop and start collecting times.
    A rain shield is now available for the BG-2 Sentinel trap.
    For other replacement items see: Green Carrying Bag #2880GCC, CO² Emitter Nozzle #2880CO, No-See-Um Mesh Catch Bag #2880CNS1.
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/7VPZE

Comment: The addition of ?: causes no selection to be made.